# How to get around PARTITION BY syntax error in MySql

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sqlalchemy

`MySql` raises `ProgrammingError` running this `sql`:

```
SELECT parents.uuid AS parents_uuid, children.uuid AS children_uuid,
children.parent_uuid AS children_parent_uuid, 
count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY parents.uuid) AS children_count
FROM parents, children
WHERE children.parent_uuid = parents.uuid ORDER BY children_count DESC
```

The error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError) (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(PARTITION BY parents.uuid)' at line 1") [SQL: 'SELECT parents.uuid AS parents_uuid, children.uuid AS children_uuid, children.parent_uuid AS children_parent_uuid, count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY parents.uuid)']
```

With schema where `Parent` can have many `children`, while `Child` having single `parent`:

```
Base = declarative_base()
class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'parents'
    uuid = Column(String(64), primary_key=True, unique=True)
    def __init__(self):  
        self.uuid = uuid.uuid4()   

class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'children'
    uuid = Column(String(64), primary_key=True, unique=True)
    parent_uuid = Column(String(64), ForeignKey('parents.uuid'))
    def __init__(self, parent_uuid=None):  
        self.uuid = uuid.uuid4()   
        self.parent_uuid = parent_uuid
```

Comment: window functions are not supported in MySQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Window functions aren't supported in MySQL. To get around this, use a correlated sub-query to get the counts.

```
SELECT 
p.uuid AS parents_uuid, 
c.uuid AS children_uuid,
c.parent_uuid AS children_parent_uuid, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM children WHERE parent_uuid = p.uuid) AS children_count
FROM parents p
JOIN children c ON c.parent_uuid = p.uuid 
ORDER BY children_count DESC
```

Or use a derived table to get the counts and `join` it to the existing query.

```
SELECT 
p.uuid AS parents_uuid, 
c.uuid AS children_uuid,
c.parent_uuid AS children_parent_uuid, 
counts.children_count
FROM parents p
JOIN (SELECT parent_uuid,COUNT(*) as children_count
      FROM children 
      GROUP BY parent_uuid) counts ON counts.parent_uuid = p.uuid 
JOIN children c ON c.parent_uuid = p.uuid 
ORDER BY counts.children_count DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Window functions are supported as of MySQL 8.0
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-usage.html